# Azure Data Factory Error Incompatible CDC option,watermarkColumn is not present

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have some data flow in Azure Data Factory (ADF) like this:

[image]

Im using "Data Preview" for makesure that data not found some error. but I run this dataflow with execute data flow in pipeline, i got some error like this:

[image]

I have search on Google, but not find or others have same issue. I hope have some anwser in Stackoverflow. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just create new dataflow on ADF, Thanks .. but until now I didn't same case/issue for this error in google result ..

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error and managed to solve it after some head scratching.

Turns out I had turned on *Enable incremental extract* by accident in the *Source options* tab of an Azure SQL source in my data flow.